# Compiling Octave 4 with OpenGL .. X11 configure script linking error

Tags: rhel, compiling, libraries, octave

I want compile Octave 4 with OpenGL/GUI support but don't know which packages to install on RHEL/CentOS system.
I only get warning:

```
configure: WARNING: OpenGL libs (GL and GLU) not found -- disabling GUI
configure: WARNING: 
configure: WARNING: I didn't find the necessary libraries to compile native
configure: WARNING: graphics.  It isn't necessary to have native graphics,
configure: WARNING: but you will need to have gnuplot installed or you won't
configure: WARNING: be able to use any of Octave's plotting commands
configure: WARNING:
```

Any suggestions which OpenGL packages to install?

EDIT:
config.log shows:

```
configure:24012: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -pthread -fopenmp   conftest.c -lGL  -lm   >&5
/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6: undefined reference to `xcb_wait_for_reply64'
/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6: undefined reference to `xcb_poll_for_reply64'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:24019: $? = 1
```

Uploaded config.log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m89kukk5kfyjkky/config.log?dl=0

Comment: Look at the `configure.log` to see what libraries it is searching for.

Comment: I added additional information. Please check.

Comment: I think it's better to ask a new question because it doesn't seem to concern OpenGL and it's a new issue

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni He could just rename the question as necessary.

Comment: Post the whole `config.log`. If it's too large, you can paste it somewhere and add a link. But I think SE questions accept up to 30,000 chars.

Comment: Asking a new question with the same content was a bad idea. Now you have two identical questions, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I deleted new question.

Comment: I'm uploaded config.log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m89kukk5kfyjkky/config.log?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

To obtain OpenGL support for your Octave-4.0.0 build you have to install the following packages

```
yum install mesa-libGL mesa-libGLU mesa-libGL-devel mesa-libGLU-devel
```

Comment: I added additional information. Please check.

Comment: this doesn't seem to solve the warning problem in my machine...I still get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with `libxcb` library. My system had older `libxcb` library which doesn't support of `xcb_wait_for_reply64` and `xcb_poll_for_reply64` function calls. After `libxcb` upgrade problem has gone.